# Which plugin will let me relate one post to another?

Tags: posts, plugin-recommendation

Here is what I am trying to do:
I am trying to allow users to create a post under 'category-A'. Then Create a post under 'category-B' which is linked to the post under 'category-A'

For example:

category-A
Post Title

Post content...

link to additional post under category-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate those connections automatically, based on a certain algorithm, then [YARPP](http://www.yarpp.org/) would probably do the job nicely.

If you want control over each connection, then you might want to take a look at [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/).

Answer (score 0):

How about [Yet Another Related Posts Plugin](http://www.yarpp.org/)? That should do everything you need and more. Be forewarned, it can hamper site load time, so cacheing is strongly suggested (by me).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a related posts plugin like
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/related-links/ or the ones mentioned above.